# Make the cursor move parallel to the detected plane like in iOS Measure app

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I am trying to make a bit similar app to iOS's Measure app in which now I'm trying to make a white cursor on a horizontal plane which will move parallel to the horizontal plane.

I've done detecting the horizontal plane with ARKit with RealityKit but my question is, how to make a strip circle with only a border radius? I want to make moving cursor like the iOS app. I am attaching the [reference video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yIHqeD2BAcswalzP3gT8_Q_U_hS2xZPq/view?usp=sharing).

I am a bit new to this RealityKit. Please help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this swift package [FocusEntity](https://github.com/maxxfrazer/FocusEntity) to drop it straight into your app.

https://github.com/maxxfrazer/FocusEntity

There's an example project in there, as well as documentation.
I wrote the package, so feel free to shoot any questions to me here or twitter (same username)